# Symfony 2 and Swiftmailer not working with file spooling

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-2.7

I can't get the file spooling to work properly with Symfony 2 and Swiftmailer.

This is my config

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport:      %mailer_transport%
    host:           %mailer_host%
    username:       %mailer_user%
    password:       %mailer_password%
    spool:
        type: file
        path: '%kernel.root_dir%/spool'
    port:           %mailer_port%
    encryption:     %mailer_encryption%
    sender_address: %mailer_sender_address%
```

When I send an email, a file is created in app/spool/default/

I then run

```
php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send
```

and get this response

```
[2015-12-29 18:54:40] Processing default mailer... 1 emails sent
```

So it looks like it has worked, but nothing is sent and /var/log/mail.log does not show any new emails.

When I had the config set to memory spooling, the emails were working without any issue, all I changed was config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    spool: { type: memory }
```

changed to

```
swiftmailer:
    spool:
        type: file
        path: '%kernel.root_dir%/spool'
```

I'm using sendgrid and postfix to actually send out the emails, but I'm not sure that the emails are even getting to postfix, so that probably doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you tested with symfony 2.8 or 3.0? It could be a internal bug when unserialize email file content. Also, even though you've said it works when setting type as memory, you should to try with gmail smtp too.

Comment: I've not tried other version yet. But based on a similar issue I'm having (with memory spool in Commands) I'm suspicious that it's an issue with the transport I'm getting for my mailer. In my other issue I keep getting the NullTransport when the command terminates and flushes the queue.

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: Not yet, but once I figure it out I'll post the answer here

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the bug with the exact config you have given, but no luck. Probably the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Is your console command running in the correct environment?  Do you have alternate dev settings for swift mailer to not actually send the emails?

Comment: As @Codezilla mentioned, check you don't have:    
`disable_delivery: true` in your config.yml file of the environment you are using

Comment: Could it be a permission issue on your spool directory? @mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the default environment. All I needed to do was specify an environment other than dev

```
php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
```